# performance issue in tomcat

Tags: tomcat6, apache-2.4, mod-jk

I have a load balancer, under load balancer I have to apache webservers with Mod_jk.

Sticky session enabled in both load balancer and webservers.

I have two tomcat servers(both are clustered/session replication is enabled)

Sometimes we are seeing continuous hit from some single IP(Hopefully,they are not from Bots).

Causing site inaccessible and we are performing server restarts.

Continuous hit from single IP is odd..is there anything I can block the IP which is suspicious and again unblock after sometime without restarting web/application server?

Comment: Block the IP in your load balancer?

Comment: But I need to do this in either webserver or application server

Comment: Block that IP in iptables on the webservers then..